# Decoding with FFMPEG on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg

I just started using FFMPEG with C++ and try to code an audio decoder then write the decoded audio into a file.

However i'm not sure about which data to write to the output file. As far as i know from looking at the sample codes it seems to be the `AVFrame -> data[0]`. 
But when i try to print it on the consoles, i get some random numbers that are different each time i run the program. And when i try to write this `AVFrame->data[0]` into a file i keep getting an error.

So my question is how can I write the decoded audio after I call the function `av_codec_decode_audio4` ?

Below I attached my code and I pass the argument "C:\02.mp3" which is a path for a valid mp3 file on my PC.

Thank you for your help.

```
// TestFFMPEG.cpp : Audio Decoder
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

extern "C" {
    #include <avcodec.h>
    #include <avformat.h>
    #include <swscale.h>

}

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int audioStream = -1;

AVCodec         *aCodec;
AVPacket        avPkt;
AVFrame         *decode_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

AVCodecContext  *aCodecCtxt;
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtxt = NULL;

if(argc != 2) {     // Checking  whether there is enough argument
    return -1; 
}

av_register_all();  //Initialize CODEC
avformat_network_init();
av_init_packet (&avPkt);


 if (avformat_open_input (&pFormatCtxt, argv[1],NULL,NULL)!= 0 ){ //Opening File
     return -2;
 }

 if(avformat_find_stream_info (pFormatCtxt,NULL) < 0){ //Get Streams Info 
     return -3; 
 }

 AVStream *stream = NULL;
 //av_read_play (pFormatCtxt); //open streams


 for (int i = 0;  i < pFormatCtxt->nb_streams ; i++) { //Find Audio Stream
     if (pFormatCtxt->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO){
         audioStream =i;
     }
 }

 aCodecCtxt = pFormatCtxt ->streams [audioStream]->codec; // opening decoder   
 aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder( pFormatCtxt->streams [audioStream] ->codec->codec_id);

 if (!aCodec) {
     return -8;
 }

 if (avcodec_open2(aCodecCtxt,aCodec,NULL)!=0) {
     return -9; 
 } 

int cnt = 0;

while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtxt,&avPkt) >= 0 ){

    if (avPkt.stream_index == audioStream){
        int check = 0; 
        int result = avcodec_decode_audio4 (aCodecCtxt,decode_frame,&check, &avPkt);
        cout << "Decoded : "<< (int) decode_frame->data[0] <<", "<< "Check : " << check << ", Format :" << decode_frame->format <<" " << decode_frame->linesize[0]<< " "<<cnt <<endl;
    }
    av_free_packet(&avPkt);
    cnt++;
}


return aCodec ->id;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right.

The data that you decode contain at the **pointer** `decode_frame->data[0]`. Data size in bytes is `decode_frame->linesize[0]`, the number of audio samples is `decode_frame->nb_samples`.

Thus, you can copy the audio data into your own buffer as follows:

`memcpy(OutputBuffer, decode_frame->data[0], decode_frame->linesize[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ffms2 which will directly give you decoded audio sample. It internally used ffmpeg/libav. So you don't have to worry about decoding stuff.

https://code.google.com/p/ffmpegsource/